# How do I use the translate directive on ng-content?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ngx-translate, angular7, ng-content

I'm using `@ngx-translate` version 11.0.0

I have a custom component that has a `<ng-content></ng-content>` included in it's content.

When I apply a translate directive on my component, it doesn't target the content. How do I fix this?

```
<app-my-component translate>translate.this</app-my-component>
```

Comment: If your component has simple text in it then you can use translate directive directly. `<app-my-component>{{'translate.this'|translate}}</app-my-component>. If  you have any specific scenario then let me know.

Comment: @SunilSingh That's the solution I'm using right now, and it feels really clunky

Comment: then why don't you create one small directive like `mytransalate` and use the @ngx translate service into it. That should solve your issue.

Comment: I have the same problem... did you find a less clunky solution?